# How would I create a viewmodel which contains parent and child data from a selectmany method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Reservation {

    public Guid ReservationId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class Passenger {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ReservationId { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckedIn { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class PassengerViewModel {

    public string Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class ManifestController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpGet("date/{date}")]

    public IQueryable<PassengerViewModel> Get(string date) {
        var passengers = context.Reservations
            .Where(x => x.Date == date)
            .SelectMany(p => p.Passengers.Select(x => new PassengerViewModel {
                Date = p.Date,
                Passengers = p.Passengers.Where(x => x.IsCheckedIn)
            }));
        return passengers;
    }

}
```

Specifications:

1. The PassengerViewModel should contain only one record
2. Based on the date field as input, the query finds all the checked-in passengers and creates the viewmodel.
3. The output should be something like this:

Date: 2021-05-01

Passengers:
Smith
Jones
Brown

I don't know if this is even possible, maybe I'm asking for too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first you have to fix Passenger class

```
public class Passenger {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ReservationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckedIn { get; set; }

}
```

I don' t think it is possible to query it since your view model passangers are not queryable, just IEnumerable

```
public PassengerViewModel Get(string date)
{
 return new PassangerVievModel {
           Data=date,
           Passangers= context.Passengers
            .Where(x => x.IsCheckedIn &&  x.Reservation.Date == date)
            .ToList()
             };
}
```

if you remove .ToList() Passangers will be queryable, but then you will have the syntax error. You have to ask your teacher what should be queryable. But I don't see any sense in it since you dont have any predicates.

Or if you need just list of passengers name you have to change viewmodel

```
public class PassengerViewModel {

    public string Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Passengers { get; set; }

}
```

and query

```
return new PassangerVievModel {
           Data=date,
           Passangers= context.Passengers
            .Where(x => x.IsCheckedIn &&  x.Reservation.Date == date)
            .Select(i=> i.Lastname)
            .ToArray()
             };
```

Comment: Serge, thanks for helping me out. To add the property `Reservation` in the `Passenger` class was a good idea. With this addition, I have access to all the properties of this class and don't have to use `selectmany` which was tricky to begin with. Looks clean, easy to understand and doesn't go beyond the basics of navigation. A lesson to remember for the future!